# Disable the dates in <input type="date"> from the records in the database

Tags: php, mysql, date, input

I have a question, does anyone here knows how to disable the dates in the calendar of

```
<input type="date">
```

from the records in the database?

:broad:

insert date **->** database **->** reads date from database **->** disable date in input type="date" calendar

Comment: What are you asking ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to hide particular dates in html5 
`<input type= "date"/>`

You can use `min` attribute to set minimum date or date start from and 
`max` attribute to set maximum date limit.

It is better to use bootstrap date-picker for your requirement.

Comment: Disable I mean is can't be clicked. Anyway yes I know the min and max of the input date tag, but what I wanted to do is to call the data date from the database and be "unclicked" in the input date tag

Comment: Your requirement is to display a calendar month which shows all dates where as other dates from the month can be clickable and only some dates which are retrieved from DB should be not allowed to click Right..?? this can be done by bootstrap datepicker. please have look on it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use **readonly** instead of **disabled**. Because disabled attribute does not support for **date** input type.